# PostGIS sfcgal ST_3DArea

Tags: postgis, postgresql, citygml, sfcgal, cgal

I want to compute surface areas of a large CityGML data set. However, I ran into some issues, which I could not resolve or fully understand.

The error message is the following:

> Polygon is invalid : points don't lie in the same plane

Minimal examples:

1. `SELECT st_3darea( ST_SetSrid(ST_GeometryFromText( 'POLYGON Z ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0))' ),4258))` /*<- This works fine */
2. `SELECT st_3darea( ST_SetSrid(ST_GeometryFromText( 'POLYGON Z ((0 0 0, 0 1`**`1`**`, 1 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0))' ),4258))` /*<- This does not work: Error Polygon is invalid : points don't lie in the same plane */
3. `SELECT st_3darea( ST_SetSrid(ST_GeometryFromText( 'POLYGON Z ((0 0 0, 0 1`**`1`**`, 1 1`**`1`**`, 1 0 0, 0 0 0))' ),4258))` /*<- This works fine again */
4. `SELECT st_3darea( ST_SetSrid(ST_GeometryFromText( 'POLYGON Z ((0 0 0, 0 1 1, 1 0 0, 0 0 0))' ),4258))` /*<- This works fine, removed one point */

From my understanding in 2), the function is not able to transform the coordinates into a flat plane to proceed with its calculations.
Somehow, I am not sure if it is a bug or a feature (is the polygons in 2) invalid, why?)

***As answered by@geozelot, its not a bug, but PostGIS does not support curved geometries.***

My idea for a solution:

Is there a generic workflow/function to split polygons (e.g. 2)) in a form like in 4) triangles and then add the sums of the areas?

I would need it automated for the CityGML data set, which I do not know how to do e.g. non-automated

`SELECT st_3darea( ST_SetSrid(ST_GeometryFromText( 'POLYGON Z ((0 0 0, 0 1 1, 1 0 0, 0 0 0))' ),4258))` **`+`** `SELECT st_3darea( ST_SetSrid(ST_GeometryFromText( 'POLYGON Z ((0 1 1, 1 1 1, 1 0 0, 0 1 1))' ),4258))`

Answer (score 3):

The vertices given in `2)` **cannot be elements of the same *2-dimensional plane***; i.e. vertex `(0 1 1)` cannot be contained in the plane defined by the other vertices. Simple `POLYGON` geometries (or *faces*), no matter the `Z` component, must not be *curved*.

PostGIS does have (limited) support for `CURVED` geometries that *could* be used for non-linear *faces*, e.g.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SetSrid(ST_GeometryFromText( 'CURVEPOLYGON(CIRCULARSTRING(0 0 0, 0 1 1, 1 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0))' ),4258));
```

however, they won't solve your issue.

---

Note that `ST_IsValid` won't detect this as it does not consider `z` values; `ST_IsPlanar`, however, should detect this.

Comment: thank you for the insight and good to know that the support is limited. This is what i suspected in "From my understanding". In the real life data set, this occurs often. What could be a work around? I suggested to split the vertices to form triangles, but lack the experience to generalize it. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @fx-9750GPLUS I don't have SFCGAL available at the moment, but you could try `ST_Tesselate` and dump the resulting *TIN*s. `ST_DelaunayTriangles`(*GEOS*) or `ST_ConstrainedDelaunayTriangles` (*SFCGAL*) will create triangular *Polyon*s, but have a deterministic order of vertex usage that cannot be influenced.

Comment: I tried this on my problem.`ST_Tesselate` would not work with the same error: "Polygon is invalid : points don't lie in the same plane". For `ST_DelaunayTriangles`(_GEOS_) an empty geometerycollection is returned and `ST_ConstrainedDelaunayTriangles` (_SFCGAL_) returns a wrong and very small polygon.