# Obtaining area modified by altitude using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, altitude

How to change area calculation, making use of altitude?

I am supposing that at Z=0 is the default (geoid surface) for PostGIS. So we can expect different area when Z=800 or Z=8000... But, using the tests below was not possible to obtain different results.

```sql
SELECT ST_Area(geom) as spheric_area,
       ST_Area(geom_z) as spheric_area_z, -- ST_3DArea(geom_z) is error
       ST_Area(geom,true) as area,
       ST_Area(geom_z,true) as area_z
FROM (                    
   SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
           'POLYGON Z((-46.6342 -23.55057 800.0,-46.6342 -23.5492 800.0,-46.6328 -23.5492 800.0,-46.6328 -23.55057 800.0,-46.6342 -23.55057 800.0))',
           4326
          ),
          ST_GeomFromText(
           'POLYGON((-46.6342 -23.55057,-46.6342 -23.5492,-46.6328 -23.5492,-46.6328 -23.55057,-46.6342 -23.55057))',
           4326
          )
) t1(geom_z,geom);
```

| spheric_area | spheric_area_z | area | area_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.917999999997526e-06 | 1.917999999997526e-06 | 21688.81550103426 | 21688.81550103426 |

---

((edit after @TimothyDalton suggestion))

### Try also ST_3DArea

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_sfcgal;

SELECT ST_3DArea( geom_z) as area3d_z,
       ST_3DArea( ST_Transform(geom_z,'+proj=isea') ) as area3d_z_isea,
       ST_IsPlanar(geom_z)
FROM (                    
   SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
           'POLYGON Z((-46.6342 -23.55057 800.0,-46.6342 -23.5492 800.0,-46.6328 -23.5492 800.0,-46.6328 -23.55057 800.0,-46.6342 -23.55057 800.0))',
           4326
          )
) t1(geom_z);
```

Results: all **same as ordinary *ST_Area()***,

- *area3d_z = 1.917999999997526e-06*
- *area3d_z_isea = 21788.3* (not changes even even increasing altitude to 8000). Other projections (ex. Mercator or Albers) also not changes with altitude.
- It is a "planar geometry" (*st_isplanar = t*), so [was expected no problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401007/postgis-sfcgal-st-3darea).

---

### Notes for @jbalk and other comments

- I am supposing that we can confirm theory with PostGIS: **area increase when altitude increase** (Earth radius). 
  [image]
- The adoption of **SRID 4326** (pure WGS84 with **no projection**) is to fix the solid angle (area in steradians), so the metric area "must" (hypothesis) to increase with *Z*.

Comment: While functions like 3DDistance exist, my initial guess is that there is no functiom for 3DArea?

Comment: Hi @TimothyDalton, the function [ST_3DArea(geometry)](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DArea.html) exists, but with this query is  not working with my `geom_z`, *"No function matches the given name and argument types."*. The only examples are POLYHEDRALSURFACE, and cites TIN... Perhaps need an extension... So it is a new subquestion: **how to use ST_3DArea(geometry with altitude)?**

Comment: I see! Did you CREATE EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal; ?

Comment: Hi @TimothyDalton, good, now I am running ... But (see question where I edit) no changes in the result, seems also `ST_3DArea()` is ignoring the *Z* axis.

Comment: Does this possibly help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401007/postgis-sfcgal-st-3darea ?

Comment: @TimothyDalton, st_isplanar=true, so was expected no problem... (see edition).

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry, I am out of ideas, just been looking at other threads and found this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379566/postgres-postgis-sfcgal-st-3darea-not-working

Comment: Hi @jbalk, my objective is not to produce an volume or undulation, I need only to check area increase with the Earth radius increase.

Comment: @jbalk I edited to illustrate  that your assertion "size of the polygon is fixed" is false, because I am using SRID 4326.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Yep - Feature request?  I don't think it's possible with st_3dArea.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create your own function.  Maybe take the min Z value, then you would know 1 leg and 1 angle of the triangle.  You could use Pythagorean formula to find the other leg length.  Then you'd need to move the vertices away from the centroid by that length, then calculate the area - and you wouldn't need st_3darea.  Or, for a more approximate result, you could use a ratio of the circumference of the ring around the earth at an elevation vs actual earth circumference and multiply the area by that ratio.

Comment: If you find an answer to this, please post it.  Super interesting question.  You might look into meteorological crs systems, or maybe nasa has some resources for mapping coordinates of spacecraft from launch into space.  I'm also thinking about zones of airspace - they must have methods calculating the area or volume of different air space.

Answer (score 1):

St_3dArea will not work for this experiment.  It uses a defined spheroid of the earth surface, so it won't work for areas at an altitude above the surface of the spheroid.

I did a little experimentation and came up with some functions that will allow you to find area at altitude.

First, you need a function to find the distance between points on the spheroid.  I chose the haversine formula, and I found a function on github that I modified:

```
--Haversine formula for geodistance in km
drop function public.geodistance_km;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.geodistance_km(alat double precision, alng double precision, blat double precision, blng double precision, earthdia double precision default 12756)
  RETURNS double precision AS
$BODY$
SELECT asin(
  sqrt(
    sin(radians($3-$1)/2)^2 +
    sin(radians($4-$2)/2)^2 *
    cos(radians($1)) *
    cos(radians($3))
  )
) * $5 AS distance;
--earthdia use 2 * 6378 = 12756 for KM and 2 * 3963 = 7926 for MI
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;
```

Then you need a function to find area at altitude.  This function uses the geodistance function above to find the ratio of the geodistance on the ground and geodistance at altitude between 2 points from the input polygon.  It does this by increasing the earth radius by the provided elevation (in KM):

```
--find earth radius at latitude of 1st point in geometry
--altitude is in kilometers!!
--multiply the area of the polygon by the ratio geodistance at altitude/geodistance on ground of the 1st and Mid points of the geometry
create or replace function areakm_at_altitude(geom geometry, alt double precision)
returns double precision  as
$$
with points as 
    (select 
        st_pointn(st_exteriorring($1),1) as p1, 
        st_pointn(st_exteriorring($1),
        (st_numpoints(st_exteriorring($1))/2)::int) as p2
    ),
earth_rad as 
    (select 
        sqrt(
            (((6378137.0^2) * cos(st_y(st_pointn(st_exteriorring($1),1))))^2 + ((6356752.3142^2) * sin(st_y(st_pointn(st_exteriorring($1),1))))^2)/
                ((6378137.0 * cos(st_y(st_pointn(st_exteriorring($1),1))))^2 + (6356752.3142 * sin(st_y(st_pointn(st_exteriorring($1),1))))^2)
            )/1000 as erad
    )
select 
    st_area($1::geography)/1000 * 
        geodistance_km(st_y((select p1 from points)), st_x((select p1 from points)), st_y((select p2 from points)), st_x((select p2 from points)), (select erad from earth_rad) + $2)/
        geodistance_km(st_y((select p1 from points)), st_x((select p1 from points)), st_y((select p2 from points)), st_x((select p2 from points)), (select erad from earth_rad));
$$ language sql immutable;
```

When I test this against the st_area function with geography casting, I get the same area at altitude 0:

```
select st_area(geom::geography)/1000 as st_area_km, areakm_at_altitude(geom, 0) from test_table where id = 19;
```

[image]

And, as expected, the area increases as you increase the altitude:

```
select st_area(geom::geography)/1000 as st_area_km, areakm_at_altitude(geom, 10) from test_table where id = 19;
```

[image]

earth radius equation came from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius

---

**Sample data:**

```sql
DROP TABLE test_table;
CREATE TABLE test_table AS
 SELECT 1 AS id, 0.0::float AS altitude,
        'POLYGON'::text AS gtype,
        ST_GeomFromText(
         'POLYGON((-46.6342 -23.55057,-46.6342 -23.5492,-46.6328 -23.5492,-46.6328 -23.55057,-46.6342 -23.55057))',
         4326
       ) AS geom

UNION ALL

 SELECT 2, 800.0, 'POLYGON Z', ST_GeomFromText(
   'POLYGON Z((-46.6342 -23.55057 800.0,-46.6342 -23.5492 800.0,-46.6328 -23.5492 800.0,-46.6328 -23.55057 800.0,-46.6342 -23.55057 800.0))',
   4326
 )

UNION ALL

 SELECT 3, 8000.0, 'POLYGON Z', ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYGON Z((-46.6342 -23.55057 8000.0,-46.6342 -23.5492 8000.0,-46.6328 -23.5492 8000.0,-46.6328 -23.55057 8000.0,-46.6342 -23.55057 8000.0))',
    4326
 )
;

-- Illustrating areakm_at_altitude() function:
SELECT id, altitude, st_area(geom::geography)/1000 as st_area_km,
       areakm_at_altitude(geom, altitude) 
FROM test_table;

-- Demonstrating no gtype effect, on constant altitude:
SELECT id, altitude, gtype, st_area(geom::geography)/1000 as st_area_km,
       areakm_at_altitude(geom, 10) 
FROM test_table;
```

Comment: Make sense, and perhaps the expected difference is minimal and not detected by the precision in the ST_Area calculus, but  my objective was  only to check area increase with the Earth radius increase

Comment: My other hypothesis is that a polygon defined by SRID 4326 is not a "fixed area polygon". The fixed size is the solid angle.

Comment: I think that you are correct that the 3dArea function should take elevation into account, but it does not.  It only takes into account the differences in z values between vertices, and applies a 'stretch'.  Maybe you can make a feature request?

Comment: @PeterKrauss check out my edits - I think I have a solution for the calculation.  I can't guarantee the accuracy, but it does demonstrate the principle of increasing area with altitude.

Comment: Thanks @jbalk, all make sense and your formulas seems good. I am using [here (you can edit)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419246/7505) and it make sense for ISEA problem.